# Python: Add item to list until a condition is true

Tags: list, python

Normal list comprehensions occur this way:

```
new_list = [f(x) for x in l]
```

What is the most succinct and readable way to create new list in Python similar to this:

```
new_list = [f(x) while condition is True]
```

Comment: the condition is upon x or f(x)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Keep it simple:

```
new_list = []
while condition:
    new_list.append(f(x))
```

There is no benefit to forcing something into a single expression when it is more clearly written as separate statements.

Comment: BTW, this is more flexible than other answers, because the OP never said `x` wasn't expected to change during iteration, and if it is then actually creating `some_iterable` won't be trivial. Also, I think it's interesting that nobody's picking at your choice of syntax =)

Comment: @Mu Ming: "I think it's interesting that nobody's picking at your choice of syntax" Now that you mention it, I find imperative solutions pretty ugly ;-) But definitely we should know something about the condition... is it upon x, f(x), both, neither? solutions would be different. If the condition is upon x, the takewhile proposals look good to me.

Answer (score 8):

Use [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html):

```
import itertools as it

new_list = map(f, it.takewhile(condition, l))
```

it is the same like

```
new_list = [f(x) for x in it.takewhile(lambda x: condition(x), l)]
```

Comment: You can just skip the `list`-call and use `map` instead of `imap`.

Comment: `takewhile(lambda x: condition(x), l)` could just be written `takewhile(condition, l)`.

Comment: @Ben James - it is written in the first version. The second is just more verbose.

Comment: I see. It wasn't obvious to me that it was supposed to be an important element of the answer, since useless lambdas are used *so much*.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably wrap it in a generator-function:

```
def generate_items():
    while condition:
        yield f(x)
new_list = list(generate_items)
```

Comment: @Sven: Sorry, please forgive me!

Comment: I upvoted to negate the -1 because I think this may be as good of an answer as any.

I tried to write a version using `takewhile` that didn't expect some iterable to already exist, and found myself making a generator (that's when I decided @Duncan's answer was a clear winner).